# changing point cloud color in rviz

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am using RVIZ to visualize the point clouds I have obtained after applying certain methods, I am trying to visualize it along with the original point cloud but in different color, but I am unable to get different color even if I set the color of different point clouds. I am using latest version of RVIZ, please help me in getting the solution so that I can set the color of clouds. The color of grid and axes can be visualize easily.

Thanking You.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10192/changing-point-cloud-color-in-rviz/) by [ravi](https://answers.ros.org/users/624/ravi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-06-07

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) on 2011-06-12**:
I apologize, my fault. It was the ros-users list.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-06-08**:
It was also posted to ros-users. As a question specific to rviz, it makes sense here. I'm not sure what it has to do with OpenCV...

**Comment by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) on 2011-06-08**:
This is a duplicate. The issue has been posted on the OpenCV mailing list as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should have the color transformer set to flat and then be able to choose a color for the pointcloud in rviz.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4